# EPPlus support for sheet right to left alignment

Tags: c#, epplus

[Excel right to left alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aHh5.png)

what is the equivalent in EPPlus to using sheet right to left alignment in Excel , the only thing that comes close to that is ExcelReadingOrder.RightToLeft but it doesn't seem to set the alignment for the whole sheet

Comment: Remember to respond to comments/answers whether or not they were able to resolve your problem. Accept answer and upvote if it did.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder , I have actually up-voted the answer , but Stack Overflow still doesn't count my up-votes

Comment: Accepting the answer is possible at any reputation and gives yourself 2 reputation too :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you want to set the `View` object of the worksheet:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileinfo))
{
    var workbook = package.Workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("RightToLeft");

    //Set the worksheet right-to-left
    worksheet.View.RightToLeft = true;

    package.Save();
}
```

Comment: @MohammedKamil  No Problem and welcome to StackOverflow.  Just remember to make the response as the answer to close the question (like Alexander was saying).

Answer (score 8):

```
worksheet.View.RightToLeft = true;
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your answer?

Comment: This means that the whole sheet will start from the right direction... worksheet variable is the one added by the workbook package.